# Generate series of random 6 digit numbers, that avoids potential off by one or transposition errors

Tags: math, random, checksum

I have an application where 6 digit numbers will be assigned for the purposes of physical access control. What I am having difficulty with is finding a way of avoiding single digit or transposition errors resulting in a valid PIN (from the series of PINs for that location). We'd be looking at needing no more 1000 PINs per location.

There is no ability to perform a checksum at the access control point, as it will simply lookup the PIN against a list of approved PINs.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Generate 5-digit numbers and use the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to add a checksum digit.

Comment: The Verhoeff algorithm to build a PIN from 5 numbers and then add a checksum on the sixth would do good as well.

Answer (score 5):

1000 Numbers is very little. Just have an algorithm which generates six digit random numbers one at a time. For each number generated it checks whether that number has been already taken, and if not, adds it to the list of PINs and marks the number itself and all its single digit and transposition errors as taken. For 6 digit decimal numbers there can be 6×9=54 single digit errors and 6C2=15 transposition errors (or just 5 if you only care about adjacent transpositions), so the number itself plus all its nearby numbers amount to 70 numbers taken per number generated, or a set of 70,000 numbers you need to keep track of.

The great benefit of this approach, apart from being really simple, is that it maintains pretty much the full entropy of generating 6 digit numbers completely at random. There is no extra restriction placed on any single PIN, only on the set of PINs in total. So only if you have a considerable number of PINs that you already know, then you could theoretically use them to slightly reduce the search space for a PIN you don't know yet. The effect is too little to be of practical relevance, I'd say. Even if you know 999 of the 1000 PINs, you can exclude up to 999×70=69,930 out of the 10<sup>6</sup>=1,000,000 possible PINs, i.e. less than 7%.

Any approach which only generates 5 digits and then adds a checksum will have less entropy than this, i.e. will make it easier to find a PIN by brute force trials over that smaller domain.

A comment raised the question whether this whole thing is worth the effort. On the one hand, what's the actual chance of a collision? There are (10<sup>6</sup>)<sup>1000</sup>=10<sup>6000</sup> possible ways to pick PINs independently (and even allowing duplicates). There are approximately 1,000,000×999,930×…=product(10<sup>6</sup>−70*k* for *k* from 0 to 999)≈2.8×10<sup>5984</sup> ways to do so without the conflicts you describe. This is a *much* smaller number. The chance of having any conflict between any two of those 1000 numbers (similar to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox)) would be (10<sup>6000</sup> − 2.8×10<sup>5984</sup>)/10<sup>6000</sup> = 1−2.8×10<sup>−16</sup> ≈ 1 so such an almost-conflict using completely random choices is *very* likely (although not [almost certain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) in the mathematical sense). This still doesn't mean that any single error for any single of those PINs would have a great chance of matching another PIN, though.

On the other hand, what's the scenario you are guarding against? The chances of any arbitrary number being a valid PIN is 1000:10<sup>6</sup> = 1:1000 no matter what. So it's already fairly likely for a stranger to guess a valid PIN, if you consider 0.1% as likely. What you are guarding against is one of two things. Either a person who knows a PIN authenticating as someone else. This makes sense if you take into account that PINs entered by regular users and mistyped might in some setups be more likely than PINs entered by strangers at random. But unless the identity of the PIN is relevant, i.e. you grant different access depending on the PIN, or you keep a log of which PINs were used, this should not matter: If a person who already has access using one PIN gains access using a different PIN, so what? There is also a scenario where an observer might be watching the PIN pad, and might thus learn an almost correct PIN, and you want to avoid it from being actually correct by accident. If this is a serious concern you should consider the setup of the PIN pad, or ask users to conceal their keyboard when entering their PIN.

Comment: I really like this answer. I wonder whether avoiding transcription and single-digit errors is even worth it  with this many PINs. The probability of getting lucky with one of those given purely random PINs with no filtering might be on the same order as just guessing one of the 1000 unique PINs.

Comment: I like the expanded section. My thinking was this: if my PIN is 123456 then there are 10^6 - 1 = 999,999 other possible PINs, 999 other actual PINs and around 70 other PINs obtainable from single-digit or single-transcription errors (ignoring transcribing duplicates). If things are spread around evenly I'd expect the odds of another potential PIN being both another actual PIN and obtainable by error/transcription to be around 999/999,999 x 70/999,999, much less than 1/1000. You calculate the probability of it being possible to do; I calculate the probability of it actually happening randomly.